# HighCharts: local variable not working in "data:"

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I had a highcharts temperature gauge working when I put the javascript inline in my php file.  However, I wanted to put the highcharts code in an "included" js file.  Before, when I coded the javascript inline with the php file, it looked something like this:

```
// html and php above
// this inline code below works
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // here i simply accessed a php variable from 
    var $temperature_F = <?php echo round((($temp["Temperature"] * 9) / 5) + 32, 1); ?>;
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

      // code initializing everything else in the highchart

      series: [{
          data: [{
            id: 'temperature',
            y: $temperature_F, // value taken from php variable
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' \xB0F'
            }
          }]
      }]
    });
  })
</script>
// html and php below
```

Now, all I did was take this chunk of code, put it in a .js file and "include" it.  I now just call a Print function from the php file, defined in my .js file, passing it the php variables I need.  Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  PrintTemperatureChart(1, '<?php echo $temperatureToDisplay; ?>', '<?php echo $dewPointToDisplay; ?>', '<?php echo $relativeHumidityToDisplay; ?>');
</script>
```

From within this function, I am able to "alert" out the expected php variables that I passed in, however, when I attempt to set "data:" to one of these variables, it breaks the chart.  When I replace the variable with a dummy hard-coded value, it works.  So I know just about everything else is set up correctly.  Here's the function in the .js file:

```
function PrintTemperatureChart(unitsMode, temperature, dewPoint, relativeHumidity){

alert(unitsMode + ", " + temperature + ", " + dewPoint + ", " + relativeHumidity);

$(function () {
alert("The passed temperature = " + temperature);
var $theTemp = temperature;

var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
    renderTo: 'Temperature_Chart',
    type: 'gauge',
    margin: 0
    },
    title: {
    text: 'Temperature'
    },

    pane: {
    startAngle: -150,
    endAngle: 150,
    background: [{
        backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
        stops: [
            [0, '#FFF'],
            [1, '#333']
        ]
        },
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '109%'
    }, {
        backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
        stops: [
            [0, '#333'],
            [1, '#FFF']
        ]
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        outerRadius: '107%'
    }, {
        // default background
    }, {
        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '105%',
        innerRadius: '103%'
    }]
    },

    yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: '\xB0F'
    },

    min: 0,
    max: 120,

    minorTickInterval: 1,
    minorTickWidth: 1,
    minorTickLength: 5,
    minorTickPosition: 'inside',
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    minorTickColor: 'black',

    tickInterval: 10,
    tickWidth: 2,
    tickPosition: 'inside',
    tickLength: 10,
    tickColor: 'black',



    },

    series: [{
    name: 'Temperature',
    data: [$theTemp], // this doesn't work
                              // this is the js var set to the passed in temperature
                              // I've also just tried using the param directly
                              // only a hard coded value will work
                              // i.e. data: [56],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' \xB0F'
    }
    }]
});
});
```

}

I just need to use these variables passed in as data in my chart.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like $theTemp is being passed in as a string. Does the hard coded value work if you use `data: ['56']`? If not, you might be able to fix the issue by using `PrintTemperatureChart(1, <?php echo json_encode($temperatureToDisplay); ?>, ...`

Comment: Thanks for the response. OK, no, if I use
data: ['56'],
it doesn't work.  OK, so there isn't any conversion I can do within the .js file?  Doe I need to include any json libraries to run the code you suggested?

Comment: json support is included in php by default. You could also convert the value in the .js file using parseInt or parseFloat: `var $theTemp = parseFloat(temperature);` However, I would suggest you json_encode from your PHP script, as it will make your javascript more robust.

Comment: OK, this didn't quite solve the problem yet...I now have
`<script type="text/javascript">
PrintTemperatureChart(1, '<?php echo json_encode($temperatureToDisplay); ?>', '<?php echo json_encode($dewPointToDisplay); ?>', '<?php echo json_encode($relativeHumidityToDisplay); ?>');
</script>`

Maybe I should try doing `json_encode` assignments before passing them...

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the values: `PrintTemperatureChart(1, <?php echo json_encode($temperatureToDisplay); ?>, `

Comment: OK, I've tried a couple different variations of things. Without using the `json_encode`, just removing the single quotes, the alerts stop showing up.  With single quotes, correct alerts show up.  Either way, quotes or no quotes, with `json_encode` no alerts or chart.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Where would I see errors, like some kind of error log in firebug or something?  I don't think I've ever seen a js error, at least not like you would see a PHP error rendered on the screen.

Comment: The console tab of firebug will show any javascript errors.

Comment: OK, I've solved the problem. It appears that adding single quotes around the PHP parameters converted/casted them into a string. That was actually the only problem I had originally.  However, as I was trying to root out the problem (and before I posted this question) somewhere along the way I had a duplicate rendering field in my markup. So it turns out I don't even need the `json_encode` at all, but I thank you very much for drawing my attention to the single quotes and making your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing single quotes around the PHP code like this:

```
PrintTemperatureChart(1, '<?php echo $temperatureToDisplay; ?>');
```

these variables were being passed as strings, which is incompatible with the integer type the "data" field expects in HighCharts. Solution:

```
PrintTemperatureChart(1, <?php echo $temperatureToDisplay; ?>);
```